# Rails select_tag with i18n translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have the following select_tag and would like to have the labels translated. I am using Rails Internationalization (I18n) API

Now, this code works how ever I need to translate the option label.

```
<%=  select_tag "object", 
 "<option value=address>Address</option>
  <option value=Orden>Orden</option>".html_safe %>
```

I have tried:

```
<%=  select_tag "object", 
 "<option value=address><%= t('address').capitalize %></option>
  <option value=Orden>Orden</option>".html_safe %>
```

But I get a syntax error. I have also tried:

```
<%=  select_tag "object", 
 "<option value=address> t('address').capitalize </option>
  <option value=Orden>Orden</option>".html_safe %>
```

The last one will not translate and just put the string 't('address').capitalize'

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into `options_for_select(args)`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

```
options_for_select([[t('address'), "address"], ["orden", "orden"]], params[:the_selected_one])
```

you would do:

```
<%=  select_tag("object", options_for_select([[t('address'), "address"], ["orden", "orden"]], param[:the_selected_one])) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `options_for_select` instead raw HTML options.

Check code below.

```
select_tag "object", options_for_select([t('address').capitalize, "address"], [t('order').capitalize, "order"])
```

Also you can use a Model to build the Select options. Please, check the documentation below for more information.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag